# Cut part of the string between two characters without knowing the length of it

Tags: python, string

So, lets suppose I have some string:

```
my_string = 'some|thing|ishere'
```

and I want to extract 'thing' from it, but I do not know that its length.

Basically, how do I extract everything that is between | and | ?

Comment: `my_string.split('|')[1]` ? Done?

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect